# Extracting individual readings from array by useing column and row names

Tags: r

If I have part of an array extracted as below named "Testrun" of temperatures
 at global coordinates as below

```
        88.54   86.65     84.75  82.85

    0     245.93 245.50 243.67 246.60
 1.88     245.93 245.54 244.03 246.94
 3.75     245.94 245.58 244.39 247.28
 5.62     245.94 245.62 244.75 247.61
 7.5      245.95 245.66 245.11 247.95
```

I named the columns be degrees of longitude and the rows by degrees of latitude for the whole array before extracting "Testrun".

I can now extract any individual value by the following

```
   > Testrun[3,2,1]
     [1] 245.58
```

But I can't get the same result using the column and row names

```
>
Testrun[3.75,86.5,1]
Error in Testrun[3.75, 86.5, 1] : subscript out of bounds
```

Surly that can be done , so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What class is `Testrun` ? An array ? What's the souce data `dim` ?

Comment: Also `Testrun[3.75, 86.5, 1]` - there is no `86.5` in your output. There is `86.65`...

Comment: I rounded the latitude and longitude. Perhaps that my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, without seeing the data im assuming you have a multi-dim data, something like

```
data <- array(1:27, dim=c(3,3,3), dimnames = list(11:13,11:13,11:13))
```

in order to access the element at position `(2,2,2)` you can do

```
data[2,2,2]
```

but accessing using dimnames you can't do

```
data[12,12,12]
Error in data[12, 12, 12] : subscript out of bounds
```

as R thinks it's 12th element. You need to wrap it in quotes, i.e.

```
data["12","12","12"]
[1] 14
```

Comment: Thank you rbm. I got it, you advise was correct. Also I had rounded the lon lat and once I undid that, it work perfectly